# Windows Explorer Dialog broken

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dialog

I have had this for the past month and I have had this problem:

[image: [problem](https://i.gyazo.com/c701a3bb6128076ee948c68790705fe5.png)]

Visual Studio gives error while i try to open project folders directly via dropdown, and when any/every application uses explorer to select a file this happens, no LeftBar favorites/drives/files, no TopBar and better i cant go back or forward to navigate explorer correctly.

I installed Universal Theme Patcher a week before this started happening and when it did i uninstalled it but still the error remains - I have not seen this before or come across it so i am hopeless, i dont even know what to call the error/bug.

Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)

Comment: I would use SFC to repair the corruption to your system and avoid software like the "universal theme patcher" in the future

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, i started a sfc scan.. will reply later when its finished if it works. Thanks ;)

Comment: This doesn't sound like behavior for the theme patcher, but rather one of the components people use for various themes which disables certain navigation bars in order to emulate different versions of windows or to make things look sleek. Have you uninstalled those as well?

Comment: Yes, i also uninstalled Numix to check if it would work - The sfc scan worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem (for me), I uninstalled Universal Theme Patcher and Numix Icon pack (Numix replaces certain DLL's and that may of been the problem). Once done a Scan was required to clean up any leftover/corrupted files, Open Command Prompt as Administrator and type `sfc scannow` and it will take some time but once finished restart and the dialog is fixed and working once again.